# Post parameter to Rest API

Tags: json, api, rest

I need to post a json data and it's parameter to REST API. I know there might be some issues when using json in cross domain, but I tried using mozilla addon "http requester" and using "php-curl" and getting result in a json format as {"success":false}.

Is there any way to inspect the REST API using json data? If so please provide me some example to pass a json data to a REST API using a parameter.

Comment: Yes, and what language? PHP I guess. Add proper tag please.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass a json data to a REST API using a parameter'? A `POST` contains the resource representation in the *body*.

Comment: I mean send a json data in "POST" method along with a parameter. Actually I'm new to API side. So please let me know how to send a parameter and its value in json format to the API using any inspecting UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you have curl installed, at the command line you can do:

```
curl -d "{\"success\": false}" http://path/to/api?param=value
```

Comment: The API doesnot support http GET method, it supports only POST method.

Comment: This is a post, with a GET parameter. If it doesn't support GET, what do you mean by "POST along with a parameter"?